# convert date format from 'DD\MM\YYYY' to 'MM\DD\YYYY' in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to insert a date value in the format of `mm\dd\yyyy` to SQL Server.
In my source .csv file its in the format `dd\mm\YYYY`. Is it possible to insert a datefield to SQL Server in this format?

Thanks...

Comment: You don't insert date value into a DB in any particular string format. Your issue is turning string value stored in CSV file into a DateTime instance, which has nothing to do with sql server. I am not sure how to do that in SSIS.

Comment: In ssis we can change the format to mm\dd\yyyy by using the substring function ,etc...but when we trying to insert it into the database it will taken as yyyy-mm-dd..

Comment: @siva...can we change the YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss.ms of sql to mm-dd-yyyy? or we can only change the view of date in other formats?

Comment: Check out the fast parse option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186291/import-string-date-in-derived-column

Comment: @Siva date isn't stored in sql server in any particular string format.  It is likely an integer or a decimal. Again, his issue has nothing to do with sql server, and everything with reading date correctly from csv file.

Answer (score 3):

In the dataflow add a derived column transformation.
Create a new derived column and change its expression to

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(TextDate,7,4) + "-" + 
    SUBSTRING(TextDate,1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(TextDate,4,2))
```

You can then map this column to your sql server destination column

Comment: Is it not tradition that at this point you mark this as the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a dataflow transformation `Data conversion` and choose `DT_DATE` as output type.

The string in  input (from your Excel file) will be convert to date object (if your table column is not typed as date).

Otherwise, you can add a  dataflow transformation `script component` to parse your string and transform it as demanded using C#...

Comment: That would be only a half of the work required. Second half is to get SSIS to recognize that date value is stored in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. If data conversion has a setting for it, then great. Otherwise one would have to write a custom (script?) module.